# Apostrophe when talking about ownership

Tags: punctuation

Disclaimer, not a native speaker or someone that excels in English, that's why I came here to ask.

When google searching for `Mens cosplay` googles first page recommendation is :

```
Men's cosplay
```

Then when I put in the search `Womens cosplay` only down the line I get :

```
Women's cosplay
```

And then when I search for `Kids costumes` I get another thing different, from target of all places down couple search results like this:

```
Kids' Halloween
```

My questions are : 1) which one of these is correct? 2) Is the rule same for Men/Women/Kids

**From the answers received I understood this**

For kids when referring to something belongs to multiple kids would be `kids' cosplay`

How would it be for men/women? Do I add just apostrophe at the end as in `women' cosplay`? Or no apostrophe?

Comment: *Men* and *women* are collective nouns and take the singular possessive form. *Kids* is plural and needs the plural form.

Comment: @Mick - They're all plurals: *men* and *women* just express plurality with vowel change rather than *-s*.

Comment: @tchrist I thought it had to do with grammar at the time, thanks to whoever edited the question. Knowing to which specific language part this belongs to is a kind of knowledge that I don't have as I m sure you don't have with my native language (I probably don't have it too)

Comment: 'Disclaimer, not a native speaker or someone that excels in English, that's why I came here to ask.' Our sister site ELL is aimed at addressing more basic questions.

Comment: @Mick so If I wanted to express myself by saying something belongs to women/men in plural form, would I add that s and the apostrophe afterwards? Or just women' or just women?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth thanks for the suggestion Edwin, can you or someone with the admin abilities migrate this question over there? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that _men's cosplay_ is any more idiomatic than _men's stamp-collecting_. Questions about the correct way to indicate the genitive structure, an overview of the use of attributives rather than genitives, and the dropping of the apostrophe in associative usages such as 'several working mens clubs', have all beeen covered.

Comment: @StoneyB is right. They are plurals, not collective nouns. Either way, you don't need to pluralise them. This means that we refer to men's trousers and women's skirts, but to kids' [kids's] trainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like a foolproof rule, you can use the following:

If the non-possessive form of the word ends in an S, put the apostrophe after the S. If the non-possessive form does not end in S, put the apostrophe before the S.

- women --> women's

  > *women's perception of men*
- men --> men's

  > *men's perception of women*
- kids --> kids'

  > *the three kids' parents*
- kid -->kid's

  > *this kid's parents*

With names you have a choice. I normally advise students to use the rule above because it is never incorrect. However, if the non-possessive form of the noun is a name ending in S then you can also put an apostrophe and a second S after the name if the possessive form has an extra syllable in the pronunciation:

- Chris' friends
- Chris's friends

Comment: I found a text recently that included "righteousness's sake". I changed it to *righteousness',* without the final *s*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach For goodness’ sake yes :), given that pretty much nobody adds any extra /əz/ there.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is because "kids" already has an "s" before making it possessive, do the apostrophe goes after the s: kids'.

Comment: is Men's/Women's then incorrect?

Comment: @ant No.  *Men's* and *women's* are correct.  In these cases, you create the possessive by adding *'s.*  In the case of *kids',* because the word already ends in *s,* we add only an apostrophe.

Answer (score -1):

A plural noun that ends with an "s" usually has the apostrophe go after, rather than precede the s. Kids' is a plural noun with possessive qualities. However, pronouns such as "it's" express the omission of "it" in conjunction with "is" with "its" being the possessive form. Apostrophes are really confusing, because they're used for both contractions, and possession.

Comment: You say plural nouns ending in *-s* “usually” place the apostrophe at the end of the word instead of before the existing *-s*. What’s the exception to “usually”?

Comment: "People" can precede an apostrophe instead of an "s" in terms of 
plural vs. singular, and possessive qualities.

"Children's clothes are starting to become more popular."
"It's the people's fault; why blame the elections?"
"Kids' fashion is gaining popularity right now."

Also, the question mark precedes the closing quotation marks in
Ex.
What's the exception to "usually?"

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I misread the comment. The "usually" was added, because of uncertainty, and a lack of confidence in my statements. Thank you for pointing it out; I'm still not so sure about plural nouns ending with "s" having the apostrophe precede the s.